# Determine fragment identifier from HTML page in Swift

Tags: strings, html, swift, stackexchange

For an iOS app which helps me rolling back [vandalism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vandalism) on Stack Exchange, I have a piece of Swift code which downloads a revision page ([example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/189958/revisions)) and tries to find the 'spacer' [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) just above a certain revision. It might not be clear what I'm talking about, so here's a picture from Firefox + developer tools:

[image]

I have the HTML content of this page, and the GUID of the revision (`8f9ab85f-1401-41e9-8f75-8a07b10bad32`) from the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). I'm looking for that element just above the revision header, since those are the only HTML elements with IDs on the page. I need that `spacer-9617187a-fe48-4212-9a1a-f3a366e62736` so I can link directly to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/189958/revisions#spacer-9617187a-fe48-4212-9a1a-f3a366e62736

For that, I've written a few lines of Swift code. The problem is that string handling in Swift confuses the **** out of me. Most of the language feels rather good, but I'd rather do string manipulation in SQL than in Swift...

Here is what I have so far. It works, but I was wondering if it could break in cases I haven't foreseen, or if it can be made more understandable/manageable by a future me. You see, even Stack Exchange's syntax highlighter has problems understanding it...

The input parameters for this piece of code are `html` (a String containing the content of the revisions page, e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/189958/revisions) and `revisionGUID` (`8F9AB85F-1401-41E9-8F75-8A07B10BAD32` in the example above - the API returns them in upper case). `fragment` is eventually used as output parameter. The `43` is the length of `spacer-` plus a GUID.

```
// Find fragment just above selected revision
let range = html.range(of: #"onclick="StackExchange.revisions.toggle('"# + revisionGUID.lowercased() + #"')""#)!
let index = html.range(of: #"<tr id=""#, options: .backwards, range: html.startIndex..<range.lowerBound)!.upperBound
let fragment = String(html[index..<html.index(index, offsetBy: 43)])
```

Comment: Could you include an appendix with an example of a full html page you are parsing like this?

Comment: I've added the link at a more appropriate place, I'm not sure if including the full 20 pages of HTML would be beneficial. It's a Stack Exchange link and not likely to break :)

Comment: not enough for an answer, but I would prefer _let offset = "spacer-${guid_format}".characters.count_ over a magic number _43_ with _${guid_format}_ being a default guid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how stable the precise HTML structure of those pages is, could that change in the future? Using a HTML parsing library might be a more robust approach.

Some remarks concerning the Swift implementation:

- Don't force-unwrap optionals. If one of the searched strings is not found, your program will terminate with a runtime error. Use optional binding with `if let` or `guard let` instead, and handle the failure case properly.
- Instead of converting `revisionGUID` to lowercase you can do a case-insensitive search.
- The first search string can be created with string interpolation instead of concatenation, that makes the expression slightly shorter:

  ```
  #"onclick="StackExchange.revisions.toggle('\#(revisionGUID)')""#
  ```
- Use a regular expression with positive look-ahead and look-behind for the second search. That allows to find the precise range of the spacer, without relying on a particular length.
- Put the code in a function, and add documentation.

Putting it together, the function could look like this:

```
/// Find spacer fragment for GUID on revisions page
/// - Parameter html: HTML of a revisions page
/// - Parameter revisionGUID: A revision GUID from the StackExchange API
/// - Returns: The spacer fragment, or `nil` if not found

func findFragment(html: String, revisionGUID: String) -> String? {
    let pattern1 = #"onclick="StackExchange.revisions.toggle('\#(revisionGUID)')""#
    guard let range1 = html.range(of: pattern1, options: .caseInsensitive) else {
            return nil
    }
    let pattern2 = #"(?<=<tr id=")[^"]+(?=")"#
    guard let range2 = html.range(of: pattern2,
                                  options: [.backwards, .regularExpression],
                                  range: html.startIndex..<range1.lowerBound) else {
            return nil
    }

    return(String(html[range2]))
}
```